# Beamer subsections

Tags: beamer, sectioning, sections-paragraphs, presentations, section-titles

I tried to point my subsections. I have a table of content and I want to show the subsection I will talk about before the frame in which I will talk about it. I managed to do such thing with sections but it doensn't work with subsections.
I used:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
\AtBeginSubection[]
{
    \begin{frame}   
        \frametitle{Contents}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}
```

I want the presentation to show subsection and then the page with subsection to come.
I used:

```
\subsection{Saturated Growth}
\begin{frame}
Text
\end{frame}
```

But Saturated Growth isn't shown anywhere.

Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the preamble

```
%\AtBeginSection
\AtBeginSubsection % <-- an 's' was missing here
{
    \begin{frame}   
        \frametitle{Contents}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}
```

Comment: Could I use \AtBeginSubsection and \AtBeginSection at the same time?

Comment: @КсенияЦочева. `\AtBeginSection{ some latex commands at the beginning of each section} \AtBeginSubsection{other commands at the begining of each subsection}`